# Remove terrainProvider from scene (ol3-cesium)

Tags: openlayers, terrain, cesium

I'm using ol3-cesium for creating 3D globe and cesium terrain provider to show terrain data on globe its working fine.

this.scene.terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({

url : "http://" + window.location.host + "/tilesets/world",

requestVertexNormals : true

});

But on click of a button i want to hide the terrain data or remove terrain provider from scene object, which ever is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following function to toggle the terain

```
function toggleTerrain(){    
    var scene = ol3d.getCesiumScene();
    var terrainProvider;
    if (scene.terrainProvider._url){
        //add a simple terain so no terrain shall be preseneted
        terrainProvider = new Cesium.EllipsoidTerrainProvider({});
    }
    else {
        //enable the terain
        terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
            url : '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles',
            requestWaterMask: true
        });
    }
    scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
}
```

your key snippet is

```
terrainProvider = new Cesium.EllipsoidTerrainProvider({});
scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
```

Comment: Is there any way to load terrain data of two places at same time??

Comment: I am not sure but it doesnt sound logic. what if first terrain sais is 100m and second 50 meters. What would be the visual effect in that case?

Comment: when i'm using above code snippet sometimes its loading my globe again and again in loop.

Comment: can you make a fiddle to demonstrate?